# C++/CX caught exception - how to print the full stack?

Tags: windows, exception, c++-cx

I have a Windows Store application (for Windows 8) written in C++/CX and I have wrapped a chunk of my code in a try/catch block.

The catch block is working and catches an exception, but so far I only seem to be able to print out the "message" part of the exception and not the full exception stack:

```
try
{
...
}
catch(Exception^ e)
{
   LogMessage("Exception caught: " + e->ToString());
}
```

When the exception is caught, the LogMessage outputs only the following text:

```
"Exception caught: The object already exists"
```

I've tried e->ToString() and e->Message, but both result in the same output and that does not include the full exception stack.

In C# it seems to be really easy to output the full exception stack, so I am not sure why it seems to be difficult in C++/CX ?

Comment: Updated the tags, what you are asking falls outside of the C++ standard and is just a C++/CR question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult in C++/CX because determining what functions would be in the stack requires code to parse debugging symbols. In C#, the CLR does work at runtime to remember which methods are in the stack, but in C++/CX, the names of functions are not recorded in the resulting binary. Put another way, the stack trace you get in C# depends on a C# feature: reflection.

Moreover, an exception may result from a call into code which is a plain COM API, rather than a C++/CX API. In such cases, the exception is generated from an error `HRESULT` return code underneath, not at the time where the exception is thrown. (Indeed, this is what happens whenever crossing component boundaries; this is handled with plain COM even if both sides of the operation are C++/CX) As such, the stack you would need for a trace is no longer available.

C++ exceptions do not record a stack trace. On the plus side, from native programs you can collect a minidump when an unhandled exception occurs, which lets you view the stack using a debugger if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a C++/CX program is pure unmanaged C++ code.  The CX language extension only makes it easy to consume WinRT types in your C++ code, it hides the COM implementation details.  So it gets the full treatment of the code optimizer.  Which does *not* try to ensure that stack walks can be safely performed.  Particularly so in leaf functions that don't throw exceptions.  It will readily omit setting the EBP register, the important one that indicates the base of a stack activation frame.

This is not the case in managed code, like C#.  Stack walks are very important in a garbage collected runtime environment.  The garbage collector must perform them to find object references when it collects garbage.  Code Access Security also depends on stack walks.  A happy side effect is that it now also becomes very easy to generate a stack trace for an exception.  It is even exposed in the framework api, the StackTrace class lets you walk the stack in your own code.

No simple fix for this, you need debugging symbols to have a shot at it.  And StackWalk64 from the DbgHelp api.  With odds that you still don't get anywhere because the program crashed somewhere in the bowels of a Windows function.  Speed trumps convenience in C++.